# " I'm also... " or " Also I'm... "?

Tags: word-usage

When starting a new sentence, which way would you arrange these terms?

I'm using it mid-way through a paragraph, following on from a previous point.

On that note of placement, would you ever start a new paragraph in this manner even if it related to the last?

I'm also open to suggestions for synonymous terms.

Comment: [RMIT](https://www.dlsweb.rmit.edu.au/lsu/content/4_writingskills/writing_tuts/linking_LL/sentence.html) lists some sentence connectors. 'Also' seems unusual in that it is readily repositioned after the subject (We also go walking in ...) or subject + auxiliary (We will/might also take ...). 'In addition'  would need setting off with commas as a parenthetical. 'Too' would be placed in sentence-end position in the UK. (*BrE 'Too, we go walking' / We too go walking (different meaning) / We go walking[,] too (two meanings).

Answer (score 3):

The usual position is after the verb "to be". Placing it at the beginning gives it more emphasis.